Minimum Population for Rounded Percent Increase.
I recently saw an infographic comparing growth in different government sectors in my home country. The graphic decided to represent growth as whole number percent increases, with no more information about the initial or final sector sizes.
It made me question what the smallest initial and final population sizes could be.
I found the smallest possible by just checking all values down from 100, but surely there's a better way to find the initial value.
The rounding element is really throwing me off. If the values were reported with decimal points, it would be a simple case of simplifying a fraction, but as all values are reported to the nearest 1% it makes it slightly more difficult.
Is there a formula to determine the smallest initial population size to see an increase of xxx% (rounded to the nearest whole). Furthermore, is there a way to find the second smallest population and so forth.

Percentages are fractions. Continuants of partial fractions (which see) are the way to go.
